# Run sequential processes with user input

Tags: shell-script, shell

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
tt=0
one(){
    echo "Please enter some input: "
    read input_variable
    echo "You entered: $input_variable"
    tt=$input_variable
}
tho(){
    if $tt >0; then
    {
        for i in {1..100000}
        do
          echo $i $i
          sleep 2s
        done
    }
    fi
}
(one ; tho) &
```

This is just a small example of what I want to do. User takes time to give input and currently in the mean while `tho()` starts running. I want `tho()` to run after user has supplied the input variable, may it be after 2 days. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 2):

The part that reads user input needs to run in the foreground. Only the foreground process can read from the terminal.

The syntax of your if condition doesn't make sense: `$tt >0` runs the command whose name is in the variable `tt`¹ and redirects its output to a file called `0`. To compare numbers, use the `[ … ]` syntax for conditional expressions or the `((…))` syntax for arithmetic expressions.

The braces in the if statement are useless: `then … fi` creates the same grouping already.

`{1..100000}` expands to 100000 words, then processes them one by one. To make a loop run 100000 times, use a loop counter.

Printing a line every 2 seconds makes no sense to me, but since I have no idea what you meant to do I'll leave it.

```
#!/bin/bash
one () {
    echo "Please enter some input: "
    read tt
    echo "You entered: $tt"
}
tho () {
    if [ "$tt" -gt 0 ]; then
        for ((i=0; i<=100000; i++)); do
          echo $i $i
          sleep 2s
        done
    fi
}
one
tho
```

If you want the `tho` part to run in the background, add `&` after `tho`.

¹  <sub>Approximately.</sub>